# Using exec in a for loop in python

Tags: python, exec

I am trying to run a for loop that goes through each line of the output of a command. For ex:

```
for line in exec 'lspci | grep VGA':
    count = count + 1
```

To try and get the amount of video cards installed in a system. But it doesn't seem to line the syntax on the for loop line.

Do I have to import a library for exec? Or am I using it wrong? Or both?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exec` executes Python code, not an external command. You're looking for [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constuctor):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('lspci', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout:
  if 'VGA' in line:
    print line.strip()
p.wait()
```

On my box, this prints out

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] (rev a1)
```

Comment: I tried this, says stdout global is not defined. Do I have to import something else?

Comment: Sorry, I must have screwed up something, but works now. THanks!

Answer (score 5):

The keyword [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) executes *Python code*. It does not start new processes.

Try the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

```
lines = subprocess.check_output(["lspci"]).split('\n')
count = sum('VGA' in line for line in lines)
```

Comment: This would have worked, but RHEL5.5 seems to ship with 2.4.3 and I can't easily upgrade all the systems I need to deploy this on. Upped though

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `popen` (or something similar). `exec` excutes python code. For example:

```
exec('x = 4')
print x  # prints 4
```

---

Also, you are missing parenthesis, making it not grammatical. `exec` is a function:

```
for line in exec('lspci | grep VGA'):  # this still does not do what you want
    count = count + 1
```

---

You can use `wc -l` to grab the line count in one shot.

```
import os
count = os.popen('lspci | grep VGA | wc -l').read()
```

Comment: subprocess module replaced os.popen

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this utility function in python for those kinds of purposes

(The reason to use tempfile is that if you open a subprocess and capture the stdout using subprocess.PIPE, when the stdout gets to be more than 64k of data, python just hangs forever.)

```
import logging
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os


def getPipedCommandOut(cmd):
    """
    cmd - command to execute

    gathers output of command (stderr and stdout) into a temp file

    returns the output of the command
    """
    logging.debug('starting %s' % cmd)

    temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile('w+t')
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=temp.fileno(), shell=True)
        #pid, status = os.waitpid(p.pid,0) #@UnusedVariable
        status = p.wait()
        temp.seek(0)
        out = temp.read()
        if status != 0:
            raise CommandRunError("COMMAND: %s\tFAILED: %s%s%s" % (cmd, status, os.linesep, out))
        logging.debug('finished %s' % cmd)
    finally: 
        temp.close()
    return out
```

then to use with your code:

```
lspciOutput = getPipedCommandOut('lspci | grep VGA')
for line in lspciOutput:
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: Your program (you can't blame Python for this) would hang because you're calling `p.wait()` *before* reading any output from the pipe. Your OS pipe buffer size is apparently 64k, so the program will never finish before writing all its output. Instead, you can read the pipe output *before* calling `p.wait()`, avoiding the use of a temporary file at all. Or, you could use something like [`subprocess.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) which handles all this for you.

Comment: Agreed that this is a pip buffer size issue - not a python bug. But I like the tempfile workaround for it for now. Do you think it has any downsides compared to reading and appending the string from pipe or using communicate?

Comment: Your approach would be needed if you're expecting a *very* large amount of output (more than what could reasonably fit in RAM, like hundreds of megabytes) and want to spool it to disk. For most purposes, accumulating the output in RAM is fine.